# badblocks taking really long time. or is it frozen?

Tags: ntfs, partitioning

[image]

I issued the `sudo badblocks -nv /dev/sda6` yesterday. I just woke up and it's still like that.

The [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks) says that the `-n` parameter specifies that the test should be non-destructive but takes a little longer time.

Is it working or is it frozen or what? Does anyone know?

Comment: Next time, use the -s switch to show progress.

Comment: yes yes I thought the "v" would show the progress but it doesn't and now I'm stuck ... it's still working till the moment :s :s toooo much time

Comment: My 160 GB m1.small instance took about 1.5 hours to complete with no options specified.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can watch per-process I/O activity with `iotop`. Install:

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

Then launch:

```
sudo iotop
```

Watch it for 30 sec. Does it show `badblocks` doing any I/O? If yes, then it is working, if not, it is likely frozen.

Next time you may launch `badblocks` with the `-s` parameter:

```
sudo badblocks -nsv /dev/sda6
```

this will show progress.

Comment: so I just open a new terminal and type `sudo iotop`?

Comment: ...just tried doing that now and I got `command not found`. is it a program that I have to install?

Comment: @MinaMichael Yep, just install it if you don't have. `sudo apt-get install iotop` It is an I/O monitoring app.

Comment: ...2 badblocks operations, 99.99% IO and my computer's running slow. Definitely running!! thank you soo soo much! your answer hits the spot! :D

Comment: p.s: I thought the `-v` would show the progress. oh well. next time :)

Comment: if you were running "2 badblocks operations" at once that would explain why it was extremely slow!  doing twice the work and having to seek all the time

Answer (score 12):

You can see where `badblocks` is currently positioned in the drive by looking at its `fdinfo` in `proc`, i.e:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# ps ax | grep badblock
 3772 tty1     D+    12:11 badblocks -v /dev/sdb
 5478 tty2     S+     0:00 grep --color=auto badblock

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# ls -l /proc/3772/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  3 00:41 0 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  3 00:41 1 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  3 00:41 2 -> /dev/tty1
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar  3 00:41 3 -> /dev/sdb

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cat /proc/3772/fdinfo/3
pos:    1707980816384
flags:  0140000
mnt_id: 24

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# lsblk -bd /dev/sdb
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM          SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 2000398934016  0 disk
```

So, this `badblocks` run is about 85% done.

@falconer's answer (use `iotop`) is a nice way to watch its current rate, but `fdinfo` shows you how much progress the program has made.

Answer (score 0):

Besides iotop, you may also want to look at [dmesg](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmesg):

```
dmesg -w
```

In my case, badblocks was stuck at 2.81%, there was no iotop activity and dsmesg showed the followng message on regular intervals:

```
[ 7371.945131] INFO: task badblocks:19760 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 7371.945134]       Tainted: G           OE     5.0.0-29-generic #31~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[ 7371.945135] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 7371.945136] badblocks       D    0 19760  19759 0x00000004
[ 7371.945137] Call Trace:
[ 7371.945140]  __schedule+0x2bd/0x850
[ 7371.945141]  schedule+0x2c/0x70
[ 7371.945145]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40
...
```

Not sure what the issue is in my case but it may be a bug?